# How to get all results with doctrine2 with HYDRATE_ARRAY?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

how's it going?

So, I had this DQL to push some registers of my database:

```
$orcamentoEntity = $this->queryBuilder->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('o', 'c.clientenome', 'c.clienteemail', 'MAX(oa.orcamentoacompanhamentodata) AS dataUltimoAcompanhamento', 'os.orcamentosituacaonome')
                ->from('Admin\Entity\Orcamento', 'o')
                ->leftJoin('Admin\Entity\Cliente', 'c', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'o.clienteid = c.id')
                ->leftJoin('Admin\Entity\Orcamentoacompanhamento', 'oa', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'o.id = oa.orcamentoid')
                ->leftJoin('Admin\Entity\Orcamentosituacao', 'os', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'oa.orcamentosituacaoid = os.id')
                ->orderBy('c.id', 'ASC');
return $orcamentoEntity->getQuery()->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

The result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [orcamentoaniversariantenome] => XXXX
                    [orcamentoaniversarianteidadeacomemorar] => 2
                    [orcamentodatainteresse] => DateTime Object
                        (
                            [date] => 2016-05-15 00:00:00.000000
                            [timezone_type] => 3
                            [timezone] => America/Fortaleza
                        )

                    [orcamentohorario] => DateTime Object
                        (
                            [date] => 1970-01-01 15:00:00.000000
                            [timezone_type] => 3
                            [timezone] => America/Fortaleza
                        )

                    [orcamentonumeroconvidados] => 100
                    [orcamentodatacriacao] => DateTime Object
                        (
                            [date] => 2016-05-02 20:11:08.000000
                            [timezone_type] => 3
                            [timezone] => America/Fortaleza
                        )

                    [orcamentoemail] => 
                )

            [clientenome] => XXX
            [clienteemail] => XXX@XXX.com
            [dataUltimoAcompanhamento] => 2016-05-06
            [orcamentosituacaonome] => Creation
        )

)
```

If I had only 1 register, it's fine! But how can I get all the results hydrating as array?

I'm using ZF2 + Doctrine2.

Comment: Did you tried with more than one entry in your database? There is nothing to do, your query will return all of them. I suspect that your question is only based on the method name that is `getResult()` and not `getResults()`. This doesn't mean that it will return only one result, but well several ones if they exist.

Comment: @chalasr there's no 'getResults' method in Doctrine2 :( And I have more than 1 entry in my database. If I select without the joins, I get all the entries.